# Recover zookeeper cluster from part of it's nodes

Tags: cluster-computing, nodes, apache-zookeeper, disaster-recovery

Here is the situation.

I got `6` zk nodes, namely `1,2,3,4,5,6`, in two different region, namely `A(1,2,3), B(4,5,6)`, separately.

Now `A` goes down, and we want to recover the cluster from `B`.

Which one of the two plan is practicable?

- Do we have to add (or switch) at least one more node to restart this cluster
- Or can we just remove all the other 3 nodes from the `*.cfg` file and then restart it

  Is there a better plan for this?

Answer (score 1):

You must manually edit zk configurations on both scenarios, which will take some time.

I recommend adding a 3rd region C with at least one node. In this way ensemble will be able to select a new leader automatically.

Comment: I'm afraid region C is not an option in my context, cos it's a 2-region disaster recovery plan. The thing is, RTO cost is tolerantly, and the recovery plan will be triggered manually. I was just wonder that if the zk cluster can restart properly(persisted nodes stay the same as before) on either scenario. SOS..